# Round up values to a specific significant figure in R

Tags: r, rounding, significant-digits

What would be the simplest way to round up a value to a specific significant figure?

Something like the function signif(), but only perform rounding up (not down)

For example: Round up 0.001145288 to 1 significant figure would yield 0.002

Any suggestions will be appreciated :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a function which changes the format to scientific, splits the string by 'e' and uses the information to ceiling the number.

```
my_ceiling <- function(x){
  num_string <- format(x, scientific=TRUE)

  n <- strsplit(num_string, "e")
  n1 <- sapply(n, function(x) as.numeric(x[1]))
  n2 <- sapply(n, function(x) as.numeric(x[2]))

  ceiling(n1) * 10^(n2)
}    

my_ceiling(0.001145288)
# [1] 0.002    

my_ceiling(0.0974343)
# [1] 0.1    

my_ceiling(0)
# [1] 0    

set.seed(1)
x <- runif(10, 0.001, 0.01)
my_ceiling(x)
# [1] 0.004 0.005 0.007 0.010 0.003 0.010 0.010 0.007
# [9] 0.007 0.002
```

Answer (score 5):

This function provides the desired output in the case of one significant figure:

```
upround1 <- function(x) {
         if (isTRUE(all.equal(x,0))) return (x)
         decs <- 10^floor(log10(abs(x)))
         ceiling(x/decs)*decs
         }
```

Examples:

```
upround1(0.001145288)
#[1] 0.002
upround1(0.0008145258)
#[1] 9e-04
upround1(11)
#[1] 20
upround1(-11)
#[1] -10
upround1(-0.023)
#[1] -0.02
```

Comment: It works for my example. But it doesn't work in all cases :(

Comment: If  x <- 0.0008145258, the output is 0.0016 instead of 0.0009

Comment: It also fails on numbers larger than one. For example, f(11) should give 20.

Comment: @AkselA Thanks for your input. The updated version handles the situation described by  Fah Thanchanok Sutjaritham, and it also considers cases with `abs(x) > 10` correctly.